# Mysql record missing when server lag

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, server

Customer use the app which create the order to deliver goods. In the database, it will generate the `order_delivery` table;

And then generate the `goods_stock_vary_history` table that record the changes of goods stock;

They are in one transaction.

The `order_delivery` has one `goods_stock_vary_history`.

---

But one day the customer created the order when server lag. And then he exist the app and create order again.

After a while, he say he cannot see his order.

I found the record of `goods_stock_vary_history` and its field `order_delivery_id` has value 2;

So I try to find `order_delivery` that primary key is 2.
And I cannot find it. There have primary keys 1 and 3 etc. The primary key is auto increment;

`order_delivery` has soft delete only; Nobody can delete that record.

---

The project use Laravel5.1 and the codes like below:

```php
DB::beginTransaction();
foreach ($order_goods_matrix as $order_id => $goods_matrix) {
            $goods_amount = OrderServices::countGoodsColorSizeMatrixAmount($goods_matrix);
            if($goods_amount==0){
                DB::rollback();
                Redis::del($user_id . '_good_delever');
                return $this->fail(self::ERROR_CODE, "Deliver Fail. The count cannot be zero");
            }
            if (intval($order_id) > 0 && $goods_amount > 0) {
                $goods_matrix = json_encode($goods_matrix, true);
                // Create order delivery
                $ret = OrderServices::createDelivery($exist_flag, $user_id, $store_id, $order_id, $goods_matrix, OrderDelivery::DELIVERY_TYPE_COMMON, $created_at);
                if ($ret['code'] < 0) {
                    DB::rollback();
                    Redis::del($user_id . '_good_delever');

                    return $this->fail(self::ERROR_CODE, "Deliver Fail" . $ret['msg']);
                }
                $get_history_id_arr[] = $ret['get_stock_histtory']['goods_stock_vary_history_id'];
            }
        }
        $store_goods_sku = GoodsServiceV3::getGoodsSku($store_id);
        foreach ($get_history_id_arr as $get_history_id_info) {
            $get_history_detail[] = GoodsStockServiceV2::getGoodsStockVaryHistoryDetail($store_id, $get_history_id_info);
        }
        DB::commit();
```

in the function `createDelivery`:

```php
$order_delivery = array();
        $order_delivery['order_id'] = $order_id;
        $order_delivery['customer_id'] = $order_base["buyer_user_id"];
        $order_delivery['delivery_goods_color_size_matrix'] = $delivery_goods_color_size_matrix;
        $order_delivery['delivery_goods_amount'] = $delivery_goods_amount;
        $order_delivery['operate_user_id'] = $user_id;
        $order_delivery['delivery_type'] = $delivery_type;
        $order_delivery['exist_flag'] = $exist_flag;
        $order_delivery['deliver_timestamp'] = $created_at;


        $order_delivery_id = OrderDelivery::insertGetId($order_delivery);
        if ($order_delivery_id == false) {
            return array('code' => -3, 'msg' => 'Deliver fail');
        }
          $reverse_delivery_goods_color_size_matrix_array = GoodsStockServices::reverseGoodsColorSizeMatrix($delivery_goods_color_size_matrix_array);

        // create goods_stock_vary_history
        $get_stock_histtory = GoodsStockServices::addStockVariation($exist_flag, $user_id, $store_id, $reverse_delivery_goods_color_size_matrix_array, GoodsStockServices::STOCK_TYPE_DELIVER, GoodsStockServices::STOCK_TYPE_DELIVER_DEFAULT_REMARK, $order_delivery_id, null, $order_base["buyer_user_id"], $created_at);
        return array('code' => 0, 'order_delivery_id' => $order_delivery_id, 'get_stock_histtory' => $get_stock_histtory);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason.
I created a trigger to track each `order_delivery` records after be deleted.

And then I found that `order_delivery` record is still missing, and the track table doesn't have any records.

So the missing `order_delivery`  record is not deleted by someone or some method.

So I think the missing record is not missing, it just rollback, and another `order_delivery` inserted before it rollback, that make it like missing.

And then I try to log every database operation result for getting details.

I found there is a line not deal with the fail operation.

These code is written two years ago, the transaction part is smelly, you need to manually rollback the fail operation. and `return` fail message.

The better way is like this:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
try {
    ...
    OrderServices::createDelivery($exist_flag, $user_id, $store_id, $order_id, $goods_matrix, OrderDelivery::DELIVERY_TYPE_COMMON, $created_at);
    ... 

    DB::commit();
} catch(\Throwable $e) {
    DB::rollback();
    throw $e;
}
```

After I change it, the missing record phenomenon not showing again.